# Bash script - unwanted removal of $

Tags: php, bash

I'm trying to generate a conf file for my website using bash: ./conf.sh dbu2 dbn2 pass2

**My bash scrypt**:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbuser=$1
dbname=$2
dppass=$3

cat <<EOF > /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/config.php
<?php
$DB='mysql';
$DBhost='localhost';
$DBname='$2';
$DBusr='$1';
$DBpwd='$3';
(...)
?>
EOF
```

**Output** (/var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/config.php):

```
<?php
='mysql';

='localhost';
='dbn2';
='dbu2';
='pass2';
```

**Should be:**

```
<?php
$DB='mysql';
$DBhost='localhost';
$DBname='dbn2';
$DBusr='dbu2';
$DBpwd='pass2';
(...)
?>
```

Any advise?

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` in the variable names that you want preserved (in order to prevent variable expansion):

```
cat <<EOF > /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/config.php
<?php
\$DB='mysql';
\$DBhost='localhost';
\$DBname='$2';
\$DBusr='$1';
\$DBpwd='$3';
(...)
?>
EOF
```